# Cannot add admin menu - composer module

Tags: magento2, admin, menu, composer

I am developing a new module which will provide access to a custom grid using left sided admin menu. The problem is that I cannot create a custom element in this admin menu.

The module is located under `vendor` folder, `vendor/test/test-extension`, with the following `composer.json` under module root:

```
{
  "name": "test/test-extension",
  "description": "test extension magento2",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "dev-master",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Test\\TestExtension\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

The module is included in `autoload_psr4.php`, being able to run install schema and getting models.

But, I'm not able to create a custom element in admin menu, simply it doesn't appear.

**etc/acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Test_TestExtension::testextension" title="New Extension" sortOrder="52">
                    <resource id="Test_TestExtension::testentity" title="Entity" sortOrder="11"/>
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Test_TestExtension::testextension_config" title="Test Extension"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**etc/adminhtml/menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Test_TestExtension::testextension" title="Test extension" module="Test_TestExtension" sortOrder="61" resource="Test_TestExtension::testextension"/>
        <add id="Test_TestExtension::testentity" title="Test entity" module="Test_TestExtension" sortOrder="11" action="test_testextension/testentity" resource="Test_TestExtension::testentity" parent="Test_TestExtension::testextension"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a mistake in `registration.php`. Wrong version was:

```
<?php   
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'test_test-extension',
    __DIR__
);
```

Instead of `test_test-extension` I've added `Test_TestExtension` (the module name included in psr4) and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the right to see this new menu ? In the BO : System > Permissions > User Role and modify the Roles Resources for the Administrators ?
It could be necessary to set in module.xml a sequence to be sure that your module is after Magento_Backend Module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_TestExtension" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: My module.xml looks exactly like that and, unfortunately, my resource does not appear in the user roles either.

Comment: Are you in developer mode ? If not : 
    bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
Have you launch bin/magento setup:upgrade ?
Delete var/di and var/generation ?

Comment: Yes, I'm in developer mode. I have also performed "setup:upgrade" (where I saw that my module's install schema has been applied) and cache clearing(in magento way "cache:clean" and manually)

Comment: it's very strange what's happening, because the rest of functionalities are working... for example I can use factory entities from my module

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a problem in xml files.
Have you tried to add only main menu and not sub-menu ? In menu.xml and in acl.xml. 
And just the menu.xml ? To delete acl.xml.

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work... but I've discovered that every successful node menu added, dispatches a message in system.log. For example: "Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_page was processed [] []". This is performed by Magento\Backend\Model\Menu.php, "add()" function. I will try to debug at this level..

Comment: Anyway, thanks for taking time in helping me to debug that issue. I will post the progress